# Есть input куда пользователь может ввести число больше нуля

Tags: javascript

Есть input куда пользователь может ввести число больше нуля. По нажатию кнопки  должна запускаться функция, которая выводит числа от введенного пользователем до нуля включительно.Если пользователь ввел 4 и нажал кнопку, мы получим: 4 3 2 1 0.
Я пробовал получилось что то такое(не работает) :

```
let input = document.querySelector('#input');
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.onclick = () => {
    let b = input.value;
    while(b <= 0) {
        console.log(b);
        b--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#input');
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.onclick = () => {
  let b = input.value;
  while (b >= 0) {
    console.log(b);
    b--;
  }
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <button class="btn">GO</button>
```

Здесь все элементарно, у вас в цикле условие не правильное.

`while(b <= 0)` - это означает что цикл будет выполнятся пока `b` меньше или равно нулю а поскольку пользователь вводит целое число то это условие никогда не будет `true`. Надо изменить так - `while(b >= 0)`, то есть пока `b` больше или равно нулю.